# How do I make D3 draw the axis from the start of a dataset?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

Given this data:

```
[
    {
        date: new Date("2013-11-04T13:38:04.604Z"),
        value: 3
    }, {
        date: new Date("2013-11-05T13:38:04.605Z"),
        value: 50
    }, {
        date: new Date("2013-11-06T13:38:04.605Z"),
        value: 71
    }, {
        date: new Date("2013-11-07T13:38:04.605Z"),
        value: 84
    }, {
        date: new Date("2013-11-08T13:38:04.605Z"),
        value: 85
    }, {
        date: new Date("2013-11-09T13:38:04.605Z"),
        value: 16
    }, {
        date: new Date("2013-11-10T13:38:04.606Z"),
        value: 38
    }
];
```

I have an application in which I would like to draw a graph for one week's worth of data; beginning on Monday and ending on Sunday. I've got D3 to draw the graph, but the problem is that the Monday point starts dead on the Y axis and all the X axis labels aren't aligned properly. I'm just wondering if there's a function that I could use that would force D3 to draw the specific start and end days, and if not, to at least align the data points on the line with those on the X axis. My code looks like this:

```
// set up a drawing context
var margin = {
    top: 40,
    right: 40,
    bottom: 70,
    left: 100
};
var width = 940 - margin.left - margin.right;
var height = 530 - margin.top - margin.bottom;
// d3 init
var x = d3.time.scale().range([0, width]);
var y = d3.scale.linear().range([height, 0]);
var xAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(x).orient("bottom").ticks(7).tickFormat(d3.time.format('%a'));
var yAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(y).orient("left").ticks(10);
var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
    .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")"
);

var valueline = d3.svg.line()
    .x(function(d) {
        return x(d.date);
    }).y(function(d) {
        return y(d.value);
});

// Scale the range of the data
x.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) {
    return d.date;
}));
y.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) {
    return d.value;
})]);

svg.append("path") // Add the valueline path.
    .attr("d", valueline(data));

// Add the black dots
svg.selectAll("dot")                                    
    .data(data)                                         
    .enter().append("circle")                               
    .attr("r", 5)
    .attr("cx", function(d) { return x(d.date); })       
    .attr("cy", function(d) { return y(d.value); }) 

// Add the axes
svg.append("g") // Add the X Axis
        .attr("class", "x axis")
        .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")").call(xAxis);

svg.append("g") // Add the Y Axis
        .attr("class", "y axis")
        .call(yAxis);
```

I've got a 'working' [fiddle of this here](http://jsfiddle.net/hYgwK/). Any advice would be greatly appreciated; I'm just getting to grips with D3 and this issue has me a little confused.

Comment: The x-axis labels seem to have something to do with the fact that the *time* portion of the timestamps put the points part-way between days.

Comment: Wow, nice catch! The problem was that I was generating these timestamps dynamically (so it would have the time information in there as well). Just passing a date works great. If you could write this up into an answer I'll gladly accept it. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not a D3 expert; heck I'm not even a D3 novice. It seems however that the library is paying attention to the fact that your timestamps are for a point between two day boundaries (midnight I guess).  Thus the dots on the graph show up to the right of the day labels, because it's treating time as more-or-less continuous and not at the granularity of a single day.

Answer (score 1):

your isuue is regarding the timzone problem...

I accept the fact of Timezone changes in your input ...

Incase still got problem in alignment

```
//offset to handle the Timezone priblem
var offset=(new Date().getTimezoneOffset()/60)+1;
```

This gives you the Offset of your timeZone..

(may be the calculation for offset chages check it out using log)

//Formatise the data

```
data.forEach(function(d) {
    d.date =d3.time.hour.offset(new Date(d.date),offset);
    });
```

this will formatise your date according to your timezone

Answer (score 0):

Omigosh!! I ran into the same problem with d3 axes.

The previous answer led me to finding the answer that helped me. Thanks!!!!

The problem was that D3 was adding hours to dates without telling me. It defaulted the time to something like 8:00 every day instead of midnight.

Solution:
Everywhere where I read a date into D3, I set the time with **setHours(0,0,0,0)**.

Here's some example code:

```
    svgContainer.selectAll(".dot")
    .data(spaceCircleData)
    .enter().append("circle")
    .attr("class", "dot")
    .attr("r", 3)
    .attr("cx", function(d) { return xAxisScale(new Date(d.date).setHours(0,0,0,0)) + horizMargin; })
    .attr("cy", function(d) { return yAxisScale(d.amount) - vertMargin; });
```

Had I read all the data from 1 place, I would have changed this one the data.foreach.